# Adding Rols using Select Menu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, discord, discord.py

I make a multitool bot for discord, this is a module of the the code and the library installed are discord, discord.ui, traceback, random, discordutils, asyncio
I have this code, whrite and adapted using a YouTube video:

```
    @client.command()
    class select(discord.ui.Select):
        def __init__(self):
            options=[
                discord.SelectOption(label="Man"),
                discord.SelectOption(label="Woman"),
                discord.SelectOption(label="Gender-Fluyd"),
                discord.SelectOption(label="Non-Binary"),
                discord.SelectOption(label="Other"),
            ]
            super().__init__(placeholder="Gender", min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options)
        async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            user = interaction.user
            guild = interaction.guild
            if self.values[0] == "Man":
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Man")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await interaction.response.send_message("Role Man added!", ephemeral=True)
            
            elif self.values[0] == "Woman":
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Woman")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await interaction.response.send_message("Role Woman added!", ephemeral=True)

            elif self.values[0] == "Gender-Fluyd":
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Gender-Fluyd")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await interaction.response.send_message("Role Gender-Fluyd added!", ephemeral=True)

            elif self.values[0] == "Non-Binary":
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Non-Binary")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await interaction.response.send_message("Role Non-Binary added", ephemeral=True)

            elif self.values[0] == "Other":
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Other")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await interaction.response.send_message("Other Role added!", ephemeral=True)
                
    class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
        def __init__(self, *, timeout = 30):
            super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
            self.add_item(select())

    class Role():
        def __init__(self, client):
            self.client = client
        
        @commands.command()
        async def role(self, ctx):
            await ctx.send("What is your gender ?", view = SelectView())
```

But when i run my code, this error appear in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\distool\env\scripts\bot.py", line 85, in <module>
    class select(discord.ui.Select):
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1475, in decorator
    result = command(name=name, cls=cls, *args, **kwargs)(func)
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1748, in decorator
    return cls(func, name=name, **attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Distool - User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 354, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Callback must be a coroutine.')
TypeError: Callback must be a coroutine.
```

Someone can help me please??

I have tried to replace `async def` by `await` or by `def` but it is not functional

Answer (score 0):

You put `@client.command()` above a Select menu. A Select menu can't be a command...

```py
    @client.command()
    class select(discord.ui.Select):
```

What would that even do?

Create a command, create a Select menu, and send the Select menu in the command. You seem to already be doing all of that, though, so just removing the `@client.command()`-line is probably enough.

#### Extra info

> the library installed are discord, discord.ui, traceback, random, discordutils, asyncio

Those are imports, not installed libraries. Half of them are part of the Python stdlib & `discord.ui` is a submodule of the `discord.py` library.

> I have tried to replace async def by await or by def but it is not functional

It says it **must** be a coroutine, and replacing it by `def` will make it *not* a coroutine. That could never be the solution to your problem.

If you have a look at your error you'll see it actually errors on the `class select(discord.ui.Select)` line, which suggests the error is up there (the `@client.command()` decorator wraps it internally).

Replacing it with `await` doesn't make too much sense either, that's not how the `await` keyword works. You can't just try random things and hope one of them works. You should try to understand what you're doing, it's all quite simple & basic.

> adapted using a YouTube video:

Time to stop watching YouTube tutorials. They all teach bad code, are outdated (before discord.py 2.0), and they don't teach you anything. You just copy-paste what one guy writes in a tutorial, you don't learn how it actually works and *what* you're doing. Just read the docs.